# Unable to get the second occurrence of pattern using regex substr in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR('500 ,Oracle 1234,123Parkway123aa 123, 768Redwood Shores, CA,',
                '\d+,\d+[^,]+,',1,2) "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
  FROM DUAL;
```

Expectation is to get output for second occurrence as `123, 768Redwood Shores,`
but how ever i can able to get the first occurrence pattern correctly but not second, i dint quite understand it why ? can someone please explain to me, thank you.

Comment: The problem is there is a space between `123, 768` but not in `1234,123`

Comment: removed space but still no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[TL;DR]** Regular expressions do not find overlapping matches.

---

The first match:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         '500 ,Oracle 1234,123Parkway123aa 123, 768Redwood Shores, CA,',
         '\d+,\d+[^,]+,',
         1,
         1
       ) "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
FROM   DUAL;
```

Is:

```
1234,123Parkway123aa 123,
```

It will look for the second match **after** the first match (not overlapping with the first match); so would be looking for the second match in the sub-string:

```
' 768Redwood Shores, CA,'
```

and does not find anything.

Even if regular expressions did support overlapping matches (they don't) it would not find anything as there is a space after the comma which your pattern does not match.

This will allow for overlapping matches (but is much more complicated and is not a single function):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/346)

**Query 1**:

```
WITH data ( value ) AS (
  SELECT '500 ,Oracle 1234,123Parkway123aa 123, 768Redwood Shores, CA,'
  FROM   DUAL
),
pos ( value, match, pos, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+,\s*\d+[^,]+?(\d*),', 1, 1 ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, '\d+,\s*\d+[^,]+?(\d*),', 1, 1, 0, NULL, 1 ),
         1
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '\d+,\s*\d+[^,]+?(\d*),', pos, 1 ),
         REGEXP_INSTR( value, '\d+,\s*\d+[^,]+?(\d*),', pos, 1, 0, NULL, 1 ),
         lvl + 1
  FROM   pos
  WHERE  pos > 0
)
SELECT match
FROM   pos
WHERE  pos > 0
AND    lvl = 2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/346/0)**:

```
|                   MATCH |
|-------------------------|
| 123, 768Redwood Shores, |
```

Comment: if i remove space also im not able to get the output here is my query SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         '500 ,Oracle 1234,123Parkway 123,768Redwood Shores 334, CA,',
         '\d+,\d+[^,]+,',1,2
       ) "REGEXPR_SUBSTR"
FROM   DUAL;

Comment: @Jfrd As I said, that is because your matches overlap and it will look for the second match **after** the first finishes and **cannot** look for it overlapping the first match (as that is not how regular expression matches work).